# Windows 10 Toggling Between "Power Saver" and "High Performance" Power Options Bug

Tags: windows-10, laptop, cpu, battery

I use my laptop for everything from gaming to work to watching films.

I'll often take my laptop off charge when streaming movies in another room, for example.  Usually when I do this I'll drop the power settings to `Power Saver` which throttles the processor's cores to sub 1000MHz (I use CPUID HWMonitor to monitor this).

Say then I decide to do some gaming and the laptop is still charged from being previously connected.  I'll return it to its DC charge, up the power settings to `High Performance` and no problem - it idles at 3000 - 3400MHz.

However, if I let the battery die, return it to its charge, wake it from sleep and then change power options to `High Performance` the CPU idles at bizarre fluctuating speeds - anywhere from 1900 - 3300Mhz.  It seems to continue to stay between these speeds while gaming.  In previous tests while gaming it usually locks at 3200 - 3300MHz (temperature permitting).

A reboot solves the problem.  However I should add that I can have a lot of applications open/chrome tabs open, so saving the state of my session is really useful for me - reboots are annoying.

Any ideas why?